# laplace convolution with Bessel function

Tags: complex-analysis

$$\int_{0}^{t}e^{a\tau}J_{0}(b(t-\tau))d\tau.$$

This functions appears in the Laplace inverse transform. It is the Laplace convolution of exponetial and Bessel function. Is there anyone know some property of this function? e.g. bound, graph. or where can i find the related result?

Comment: For $a=b=1$ and $t\ge2$, we have $I(t)\simeq\dfrac1{\sqrt2}$

Comment: How did you know that?

Comment: You may exploit the fact the Laplace transform of $J_0(x)$ is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+t^2}}$ while the inverse Laplace transform of $e^{ax}$ is $\delta(a+t)$.